# Meteor JS Error "ReferenceError: X is not defined"

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript, papaparse

I have installed a package using this command meteor add harrison:papa-parse. Then I used it in my script but an error message "ReferenceError: Papa is not defined". Do I need to do something else?

```
doStuff = (data) ->
  console.log data

parseData = (url, callBack) ->
  Papa.parse url,
    download: true
    dynamicTyping: true
    complete: (results) ->
      callBack results.data

Meteor.startup ->
  parseData "tests/sample.csv", doStuff
  return
```

Comment: You're trying to use `Papa` on the server? [It is only added to the client](https://github.com/harrisonhunter/papa-parse-meteor/blob/master/package.js#L11).

Comment: @PeppeL-G yes your correct. Any idea?

Comment: @PeppeL-G oh i see.  I am new in meteor js. Can I fork this and change it to server and include it to my package?. Would that be good?

Comment: That's up to the package author. If I were you, I would create an issue about it on the package's GitHub page. You can also create your own package that adds `Papa` on the server. Just copy his package and change the line of code I linked to earlier to `api.addFiles('papa-parse.js', ['client', 'server']);` or `api.addFiles('papa-parse.js', 'server');`, depending on desired functionality.

Comment: @PeppeL-G Can you make it an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`harrison:papa-parse` only adds `Papa` on the client, so you can't use it on the server.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [**harrison:babyparse**](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/BabyParse) which provide papa-parse library on the server side.